# j2me touch gui looking like android

Tags: android, user-interface, java-me, touch, port

i would like to remake a program i made for android
in android it looks pretty nice and is very touch friendly

now i need to make it for symbian
what would be the best approach to achieve similar graphics and functionality

i tried searching in j2me
but the graphics look so very outdated :(

here are some screens of the android interface
http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j74/bertyhell/krist/datacheck.png
http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j74/bertyhell/krist/datacheck1.png

i just need to make sure the buttons are big enough
and that scrolling can be done with hand gestures

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a good way.

- You can solve buttons by CustomItem as BlaXpirit mentioned.
- You can use Canvas and implement it or your own, but text editing will not be comfortable: if you want inline text editing, it can't support builtin T9, copy&paste and so on unless you are using MIDP 3.0. I don't know any device that supports MIDP 3.0.
- You can look for a GUI framework instead of implementing it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

LWUIT is very themeable, so you can make things look pretty much anything you want. Adding padding/margins is simple.

Have a look through this blog http://lwuit.blogspot.com/ by one of the LWUIT developers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do it.
I think you have to implement the "look" by yourself. And this is very, very, very difficult.

Suggestions? Learn J2ME programming, particularly `Canvas`. Or, what is best, don't try to achieve this. Just use J2ME's `Form`s

Comment: what would be the best approach to get the same functionality?

cause now i get really small buttons ans setwidth doesn't help.

touch buttons should be pretty big.

Comment: If you are using Forms, try to use `CustomItem`